# Adding more than one image in front of video in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm using this command to put image in fromt of video in ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input -i myimage -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:port
```

I need to put another image in differant position but on the same video, is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use

```
ffmpeg -re -i input -i image1 -i image2 \
       -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10[a];[a][2]overlay=W-10:10" \
       -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:port
```